# Upgraded to 17.1 and swap partition is not longer used

Tags: swap, partitioning

And my box keeps grinding to a halt.

I had to upgrade, as 17.04 was no longer supported, but the upgrade appears to have given me a swap file, and no longer uses the swap partition.

How do I map back to the partition?

/etc/fstab :

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=9de838cb-5616-47d1-9126-a00a8a14dc57 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
 # /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E60E-9AF6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

sudo lsblk -f

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                         
├─sda1 vfat   SYSTEM   E60E-9AF6                            /boot/efi
├─sda2                                                      
├─sda3 ntfs   OS       449C129F9C128B94                     
├─sda4 ntfs   RECOVERY F2DCDAA4DCDA6301                     
├─sda5 ext4            9de838cb-5616-47d1-9126-a00a8a14dc57 /
└─sda6 swap            694dc408-79f0-4bfb-8f6b-1299707ef8aa
```

Comment: I doubt that this just happened during the upgrade. You could try `sudo swapon -a` should mount your swap partition, you can check if swap is enabled with `free`. if that doesn't work, can you show us your fstab file, `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the output there, otherwise its very hard to read.

Comment: The output of **sudo lsblk -f** would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current configuration is using a swap file instead of a device. It is up to you if you chose to still use the file for swap. To enable swap on your device that is already configured:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

`sudo nano /etc/fstab` and add this line

```
UUID=694dc408-79f0-4bfb-8f6b-1299707ef8aa none            swap    sw              0       0
```

If you do not want to use the file for swap then place a "#" at the beginning of the line or delete the line.

```
#/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Then run:

```
sudo swapon -a
```

Comment: This is the correct way to get from a swapfile to the swap partition. What still bugs me, is how OP got there by simply upgrading ?

Comment: @ RobertRiedl It is strange, the swap partition  should have been retained.